# Factoring of the partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, partition-function

In Atkins physical chemistry pg 615, I found the following:
[image]

I did not understand how it is valid, since sigma(xy) is not equal to sigma(x) × sigma(y).

Comment: On this site we strongly discourage posting images of text and mathematical formulas. Please type the relevant parts of the image yourself. We do this because 1) Images are not editable, so other users cannot improve the post if you use images, 2) Images are not searchable, 3) Images are harder to read.

Comment: @DanielSank Sure, I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: Rather than keeping it in mind next time (which you should still do), please edit *this* question according to @DanielSank's suggestion.

Comment: First of all, the exponential function can clearly be separated into the different factors as shown (since that's how exponential functions works). Then, since rotational, vibrational, translational, and electronic degrees of freedom are independent, the number of states is just equal to the *product* of the individual number  of states for each dof. That means that the states can be indexed separately, i.e. for a fixed rotational, electronic, and vibrational state, we can run through *all of the translational states, allowing us to factor  the expression.

Comment: @march I don't know how to do the LaTeX for the equations on the image yet, will edit as soon as I learn.

Comment: We have [instructions on how to use mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me illustrate this with a simpler example. I think if you accept the following than you shouldn't have any trouble believing the formula in the book. ( I assume here that all the sums are finite, so that we don't care about convergence issues).

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{a_i} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{j=1}^m e^{b_j} \right)= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m e^{a_i + b_j}  $$

where of course $a_i,b_j \in \mathbb R$. Note that you can write $e^{a_i + b_j}$ as $e^{a_i} \cdot e^{b_j}$. Using this and starting with the right-hand side we have:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m e^{a_i + b_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m e^{a_i} \cdot e^{b_j} \overset {(*)} =  \left(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{a_i} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{j=1}^m e^{b_j} \right) $$

where I used in $(*)$ the fact that the second summation is over $j$ so that $a_i$ are just constants for this summation. It is like writing $ 2 b_1 + 2 b_2 = 2 \cdot (b_1 + b_2)$ Thus you get the equality that you want.

Comment: Thank you!!! I guess the key was the indices are all independent. I assumed all the i's were the same.

Comment: I agree that the notation is quite odd. I'd have written $i,j,k,l$ instead of $i (\text{vibrational})$ etc. or at least make it clear that they are different indices.

Answer (score -2):

Let Y equal X+1. So does sigma(x(x+1)) equal sigma(x)*sigma(x+1)? 
Clearly, NO.
So the best method is to keep it as a product. 
Summation doesn't work like that.

Comment: This is exactly my point! But in the derivation they seemed to have done otherwise.

Comment: Sure: that's true for a *general* $sigma$, but for this *particular* function, it's true.

Comment: @march could you elaborate how?